# Почему REGEXP_LIKE не распознаёт границы слов?

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle, plsql

Возникла проблема с поиском границ слов с помощью `REGEXP_LIKE`.

Следующий запрос возвращает одну строку, как и ожидалось:

```
select 1 from dual
where regexp_like('DOES TEST WORK HERE','TEST');
```

But I want to match on word boundaries as well. So, adding the "\b" characters gives this query

Но хотелось бы, чтобы поиск осуществлялся и по границам слов. То есть, если добавить символы `\b` в следующий запрос:

```
select 1 from dual
where regexp_like('DOES TEST WORK HERE','\bTEST\b');
```

То он больше не вернёт одну ожидаемую запись.

Какие есть идеи?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle REGEXP_LIKE and word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7567700) от участника [@Greg Reynolds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8163/greg-reynolds)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/7567700

Comment: Я вот тоже не понимаю почему Oracle решил ограничиться поддержкой POSIX RegEx, вместо расширенного, ставшего уже де-факто стандартным...

Comment: @MaxU Наверное потому, что отдали делать индусам (только по слухам). О правомерности ограничений Oracle нигде не упоминает.

Comment: Я еще 20 лет назад слышал, что разработчики ядра БД - из Индии. В Индии есть много толковых ребят, но выбирать нужно жестко и придирчево. Знаю не по наслышке - уже многих успел проинтервьюировать и по Oracle и по Data Science)

Comment: Идея не использовать регулярки Oracle) select 1 from dual
where instr(replace('DOES TEST WORK HERE',' ', '~'), '~TEST~') > 0 или слишком топорно?

Comment: @NMD Почему топорно? В большинстве случаев хватит простых функций. Но смысл вопроса  о границах слова именно в регулярках, а простой пример данных только для понимания того, что нужно. В реальном случае, он может быть конечно сложней.

Answer (score 4):

Самый короткий шаблон, который заменит границу слова `\b`, т.е. найдёт целое слово, это:

```
(^|\W)test($|\W)
```

См. [воспроизводимый пример на regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MKVOqx/1).

**Подробней**

- `(^|\W)` - группа захвата, совпадающая либо с

  - `^` - начало строки
  - `|` - или
  - `\W` - несловарный символ
- `test` - само слово
- `($|\W)` - группа захвата, совпадающая либо с

  - `$` - конец строки
  - `|` - или
  - `\W` - несловарный символ.

Заметьте, что `\W` соответствует любым символам, кроме букв, цифр и `_`. Если надо найти слово, которое заключено между `_` (подчеркиваниями), то нужен немного другой шаблон:

```
(^|[^[:alnum:]])test($|[^[:alnum:]])
```

Отрицаемое выражение во внутренних скобках `[^[:alnum:]]` совпадёт с любым символом (куда входит `_`), кроме алфавитно-цифровых, поэтому `_test_` будет найден этим шаблоном.

См. [воспроизводимый пример на regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MKVOqx/2).

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52441424) от участника [@Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Полагаю, что надо сделать так:

```
 select 1 from dual 
 where regexp_like ('does test work here', '(^|\s)test(\s|$)');
```

Это потому, что `\b` не упоминается в списке [Perl-influenced Extensions in Oracle Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Perl-influenced-Extensions-in-Oracle-Regular-Expressions.html#GUID-2D2B8DEB-1343-4DA3-BBC1-5A5C79A5FC20).

Символ `\s` обеспечивает, чтобы искомое слово начиналася и заканчивалось пробелом. Однако этого недостаточно, так как искомое слово может оказаться в самом начале или конце полной строки. Поэтому использую *альтернативу* (на это указывает символ `|`) `^` для начала строки и `$` для конца строки.

---

**Обновление (спустя 3 года+) ...**
Так совпало, что недсавно потребовалась эта функциональность, и кажется, что еще лучше регулярное выражение `(^|\s|\W)test($|\s|\W)` (см. блог [Отсутствующий специальный символ регулярного выражения \b в Oracle](http://renenyffenegger.blogspot.ch/2014/12/the-missing-b-regular-expression.html)).

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7567871) от участника [@René Nyffenegger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180275/ren%c3%a9-nyffenegger)</sub>