# Ограничения regexp_*: ORA-12733: regular expression too long

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle

Нужно при помощи `regexp_like` проверить большое количество, около 300, условий.

Примерно такой запрос (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f94ee6665dfe1fb56f6ac059231883ab)):

```
select * from t where regexp_like(val,'.*hk.*| .*jj.*|.*we.*.'|...)
```

Но так, как список слов/выражений в условии большой, то столкиваюсь с ограничениями при выполнения запроса:

> ORA-12733: regular expression too long
> ORA-01704: string literal too long

Попробовал разбить на части:

```
[...] and (regexp_like(col,'.*XXX*.') or regexp_like(col,'.*HHHH*.'))
```

вроде работает, но думаю, что возможно есть более элегантный способ.

Можно ли как то обойти ограничения не разбивая на части шаблон в `regexp_like`?

Comment: какая у вас версия Oracle DB?

Comment: Короткий ответ для `ORA-01704: string literal too long` - единственный способ избавиться от этой ошибки, __не меняя версию Oracle__, это уменьшить длину строкового литерала до допустимой длины. PS и не факт, что в более новой версии вы не упретесь в тоже ограничение, но уже с большей допустимой длиной строкового литерала ;)

Comment: @MaxU 12.1, 
а если разбить на множество коротких регулярных выражений и разделить логическим выражением? так получится обойти ограничения

Comment: Ну вообще-то не каждое регулярное выражение можно разбить на части для независимого тестирования... но если можно - бейте.

Comment: если в таком формате пытаться, and regexp_like(col,'.*XXX*.') or regexp_like(col,'.*HHHH*.') на сколько будет корректно?

Comment: лучше опишите, что вы пытаетесь выбрать используя регулярные выражения в запросе. пример данных и пример ожидаемого результата

Comment: @NMD выгрузить все строки, где контент в columns будет содержать одно из условий, проверить нужно около 300 условий,

Comment: 300 условий? и как потом такое сопровождать? лучше функцию написать и использовать её при выполнении select

Comment: Покажите на [этом примере](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d4a5a37ba25530a68cc9c9eab4bdcbce), что вы всё таки делаете. 300 условий не надо, хотя бы пяток. Измените там данные и шаблон и опубликуйте новую ссылку.

Comment: @0xdb (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f94ee6665dfe1fb56f6ac059231883ab) накидал, т.е. есть список слов/выражений, около 300 и нужно пройти по таблице найти где присутствуют они, я разбил на мелкие and (regexp_like(col,'.*XXX*.') or regexp_like(col,'.*HHHH*.')) и разделил вроде выгружает, но думал возможно есть еще способ

Comment: Мне кажется, регулярные выражения вам не нужны. Типичный случай [LIKE IN](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1014465/217579), посмотрите, подходит ли. Один пример уже [адаптировал под ваши данные](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=237343f5e72769319ce9f5a10b6f1da0),

Comment: Или [так без создания отдельных таблиц](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=676137cdd5142dc7ac2025bf66239350). _есть список слов/выражений_, стоит подумать, может подойдут текстовые индексы.

Comment: @0xdb попробую выполнить с созданием таблицы, как то сподручнее будет, благодарю

Comment: Хорошо, дайте знать, что получилось. Если всё получится, то вопрос перезакрою как дубликат (это лучше, чем закрытие как низкокачественный).

Comment: @0xdb вариант с созданием дополнительной таблицы помог, но, как в данном случае допустим сделать выборку по отдельному слову, т.к. сейчас он тянет все даже где патерн является частью целого слова в таблице, т.е. pattern = 'tx'  вывод 'rtx'

Comment: Границы слова https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1315426/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-regexp-like-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%91%d1%82-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2

Comment: @xcplat _как в данном случае допустим сделать выборку по отдельному слову_, надо определиться, что такое отдельное слово. Если границы слова это всегда пробел, то можно [просто вот так](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=15e7048b44a9e46b494dcb8f18f1c03f).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если учесть, что поиск идёт по большому колличеству уникальных слов, то лучше отказаться от регулярных выражений и поместить все слова в отдельную таблицу.

Пример для реализации, если границы слова всегда пробел ([с данными на db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=551799633a6df555f05219c9c85c9c79)):

```
create table dict (word varchar2 (32));

select t.*
from t
where exists (
    select 1
    from dict
    where instr (' '||val||' ', ' '||word||' ')>0 
)
```